# Save user Bookmark in MYSQL

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have one android application of Quotes. I have implemented Google Sign in function in App. I am storing user's email in MYSQL when he/she sign in. I want allow user to bookmark quotes which he/she likes. I want save it in mysql so he can easy retrieve it.

I am confused how can I mark it as favorite in mysql. My current quotes table has columns id, quote_text, quotes_author and table user has id and email.

How to store quote for user with assign email so I can easy retrieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have another table, for example "favorite_quotes" with columns "user_id" and "quote_id". As soon as user marks a quote as favorite, you should store this relation in a table. Than you can retrieve users's favorite quotes by his user_id - you will get a list of quote_id's.